# Is [NSMutableString string] same as [[NSMutableString string] autorelease]?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, autorelease

I noticed a piece of code somewhere it does
    NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString string] autorelease];

Is it overkill? Shouldn't it be the same as [NSMutableString string]?

Comment: [You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *myString = [[NSMutableString string] autorelease];
```

will lead to a crash if they aren't calling retain on it elsewhere.

```
[NSMutableString string]
```

is the same as

```
[[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease]
```

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look right to me. Are you sure that the example you saw is actually doing this?

`[NSMutableString string]` is equivalent to

```
[[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease]
```

So with the example you provided, you would get

```
[[[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease] autorelease]
```

which would result in an over release and an `exc_bad_access` error.